# In AWStats, is there a way to exclude certain urls counting towards counting as pages, but still count as hits

Tags: awstats, stats

AWStats distinguishes the difference between a *page* and a *hit* in it's web log stats.

To accomplish this, there is a configuration option to identify certain file extensions as hits, but not pages.  eg:

```
NotPageList="css js class java gif jpg jpeg png bmp ico swf avi flv wmv mp3"
```

There is also an option to skip some URLs (based on a pattern) entirely (ie not a page, nor a hit).  eg:

```
SkipFiles="REGEX[^\/ajaxcall]"
```

The problem is that I want to exclude certain URLs (eg ajax calls matching a certain pattern) from being counted as pages, but keep them counted as hits.  The first option doesn't appear to allow pattern specification, and the 2nd option excludes matches entirely.

Is there a way around this without changing the system to introduce an invented extension type for these URLs in order to use the first option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting in early in case I'm right:

No, there isn't a way